# FileNotFoundException: But the file does exist

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Maybe, this problem has been asked many times here, but forgive me since I've spent hours and I could not fix it. I am trying to load a file from my directory and show it on a TextArea. However, I keep get java.io.FileNotFoundException. Firstly, I thought the problem is the file permission, yet, after I changed the permission, I still get the same errors. I've checked many  times whether the path is correct or the spelling is correct. I even tried to paste the path from the error stacktrace to my terminal and the path is working. Here is my code:

```
private void treeFileValueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {                                      
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) treeFile.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
        if(selectedNode==null)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error");
        if(selectedNode.isLeaf()){
            String path = Arrays.toString(selectedNode.getUserObjectPath());
            path = path.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\:,]","");
            String[] _path = path.split(" ");
            String filePath="";
            int counter=1;
            for (String s : _path) { // I tried to re-construct the path of the selected node/child
                if(counter==_path.length){
                    filePath += s;
                    counter = 1;
                }else{
                    filePath += s+"/";
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            try {
                setTextArea(filePath); //passing the filePath in string format
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Preprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Preprocess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    } 



private void setTextArea(String _filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File file = new File(_filePath);
        if(!file.exists())
            System.out.println("File not found");
        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current sys dir: " + dir);
        System.out.println("Current abs dir: "+file.getAbsolutePath());  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getName())); 
        try{   
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            textPreprocess.setText(sb.toString());
        }finally{
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Below is the output:

```
Current sys dir: /Users/adibangun/Downloads/ThematicAnalysis
Current abs dir: /Users/adibangun/Downloads/ThematicAnalysis/Output/Sentiment/Sentiment20150629.txt
Jun 29, 2015 11:32:55 PM thematicanalysis.GUI.Preprocess treeFileValueChanged
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Sentiment20150629.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Preprocess.setTextArea(Preprocess.java:197)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Preprocess.treeFileValueChanged(Preprocess.java:163)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Preprocess.access$000(Preprocess.java:33)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Preprocess$1.valueChanged(Preprocess.java:75)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3387)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:188)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1633)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2393)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3609)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4530)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

EDIT:

pwd file: /Users/adibangun/Downloads/ThematicAnalysis/Output/Sentiment

ls-ltr Sentiment20150629.txt : -rw-r--r--  1 adibangun  staff  408555 29 Jun 23:13 Sentiment20150629.txt

Does anyone know the problem? Any comment and help would really be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: share the output of pwd and ls -ltr commands for your file dir

Comment: Does it work with `new FileReader(file)`?

Comment: I have tried it, but it did not work @Marvin

Comment: if you use new FileReader(file) do you get the same output?, did you copy the complete output?, because a file not found exception is thrown if the file reader cannot find the file but this message "File not found" is not displayed so the system can find the file

Comment: @AlejandroAgapitoBautista..Honestly, I tried it before, but now it works when I use new FileReader(file) instead of new FileReader(file.getName()). Many Thanks to you guys :) :)

Comment: @Marvin ..Honestly, I tried it before, but now it works when I use new FileReader(file) instead of new FileReader(file.getName()). Many Thanks to you guys :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getName()));` by `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`

FileNotFoundException is thrown if:

1. If the message of the exception claims that there is no such file or directory, then you must verify that the specified is correct and actually points to a file or directory that exists in your system.
2. If the message of the exception claims that permission is denied then, you must first check if the permissions of the file are correct and second, if the file is currently being used by another application.
3. If the message of the exception claims that the specified file is a directory, then you must either alter the name of the file or delete the existing directory (if the directory is not being used by an application).

check the next link for more information http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-io-filenotfoundexception-how-to-solve-file-not-found-exception/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that letting the thread sleep for at least a millisecond let the file be readable. If you get the exception again, sleep for 1000 milliseconds and see if it works. Use

```
Thread.sleep(1);
```

and don't forget to add the Throws declaration which an IDE like Eclipse should do automatically for you.
Let me know what you get.